# If I have all the xpath nodes of a xml file, then how can I map it to another equivalent xml file

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $counter++;
    $rootNode = getXMLRootNode($file);
    $rootNodeArray[$file] = $rootNode; 

    $tag = '/'.$rootNode;

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $xmlNodeObject = $xml->xpath($tag);
}
```

`$xmlNodeObject` stores the xpath of the xml file.

**Update**

Sample xml file:

```
<Scenario>
    <scenario_txt>
        <audioText  img_a="Anita_ss.jpg" img_b="Sarah_ss.jpg">
            <text>
                <![CDATA[Sarita is working on a high impact and                          confidential bid for the IT department. Her team is working on tight timelines. To overcome stress, Sarita takes a coffee break with Swati, a friend and colleague.]]>
            </text>
        </audioText>
    </scenario_txt>

    <branching>
        <step stepID="0" stepType="conv" speakerName="a" audioFile="">
            <audioText>
                <text>
                </text>
            </audioText>
        </step>

        <step stepID="1" stepType="conv" speakerName="a" audioFile="step1.mp3" endScenario="false">
            <audioText>
                <text><![CDATA[Hi Sarita! How are you doing? You've been working really hard, lately. Is everything fine? ]]>
                </text>
            </audioText>
        </step>

        <step stepID="2" stepType="conv" speakerName="b" audioFile="step2.mp3">
            <audioText>
                <text><![CDATA[Hi Swati! Yeah, I've been deep into work preparing the proposal for the IT bid.]]>
                </text>
            </audioText>
        </step>

        <step stepID="3" stepType="conv" speakerName="a" audioFile="step3.mp3">
            <audioText>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[So how is the proposal shaping up?]]>               
                </text>
            </audioText>
        </step>
    </branching>
</Scenario>
```

I also have another xml file which is equivalent to this but the only difference is that it has viewable content in some other language. What I want to do is to map both of these xml files so that I can extract the viewable content of the other xml file.

Comment: Post sample XML input and the corresponding expected output please...

Comment: @har07 uploaded the sample XML input. I hope you get the scenario.

Comment: I understand that you retrieve the root node in code line 1 to 5 for xpath. You could use the wildcard in xpath so there's no need to extract the root node up front: `$xmlNodeObject = $xml->xpath("/*");` - Nonetheless, I have no clue what exactly is your expected result.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I found another way to solve my problem. Sorry for late response.